# IP to domain using C++

Tags: c++, dns

I want to write a program in C++ language that returnes a list of domains for a given IP address(I thik it is Revers DNS).
 It is somthing like BING IP reverse method.
Also I am familiar to WinPcap. 
 I was tested gethostbyaddr() and getaddrinfo() and so other functions but really I couldnt do what I want.
What is the best offer??

Comment: `gethostbyaddr()` should work. Please show your code.

Comment: I tested MSDN code "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx" but not works. :(

Comment: If you want help with your program, you have to show your code, don't just link to documentation.

Comment: I exactly use this: and i am trying to add code here

Answer (score 0):

```
// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

host_addr = argv[2];

printf("Calling gethostbyaddr with %s\n", host_addr);
if (bIpv6 == 1) {
    {
        iResult = inet_pton(AF_INET6, host_addr, &addr6);
        if (iResult == 0) {
            printf("The IPv6 address entered must be a legal address\n");
            return 1;
        } else
            remoteHost = gethostbyaddr((char *) &addr6, 16, AF_INET6);
    }
} else {
    addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host_addr);
    if (addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE) {
        printf("The IPv4 address entered must be a legal address\n");
        return 1;
    } else
        remoteHost = gethostbyaddr((char *) &addr, 4, AF_INET);
}

if (remoteHost == NULL) {
    dwError = WSAGetLastError();
    if (dwError != 0) {
        if (dwError == WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND) {
            printf("Host not found\n");
            return 1;
        } else if (dwError == WSANO_DATA) {
            printf("No data record found\n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            printf("Function failed with error: %ld\n", dwError);
            return 1;
        }
    }
```